# WPF custom slider drawed by yourself

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

This is my first question on stack-overflow so don't kick it))

I have a problem trying to create a Mac-style slider control. I have found [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/MAC_Slider.aspx) and I have implemented it in my solution, but it still doesn't satisfy me cause I need a more universal solution.

Basically I need to create this slider control with the help of four pictures - right, left and center(the rest of) pictures of track bar and one picture for thumb. These are PNG files.

Could I style default WPF slider to support such resource-oriented behavior? 
I'm really astonished that all samples includes templates for style but no one supports something like

```
<TrackBarLeft>
   <Image for left>
</TrackBarLeft>
....
```

Could any one give me a solution for this problem?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sams "WPF Control Development Unleashed" has some guidelines on this.  Check out Chapter 5: Using Existing Controls - it has an example based on a scrollbar - it might be useful.