# Is it possible to put Button in WPF slider thumb?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

Is it possible to put Button in WPF slider thumb? Not custom thumb itself but simply add button on it?

Comment: What for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to make this thumb :1.Round 2.Transparent 3 Border colored 4. Display current scrolled value in it

Comment: What's the topic of your class this assignment belongs to?

Comment: @Papa John, why you can't use a custom template for you slider?

Comment: Ok, take a look at my target task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338837/wpf-custom-slider-drawed-by-yourself  I am simply trying to find different ways for solution

Comment: What's the topic of your class this assignment belongs to? - sorry I dont understand you. What is ' topic ' for you in such context? I am trying to implement custom control. this is one class - grid, stackpanel and slider on it.

Comment: Doesnt sound like Button the best choice here - why not a Label (in a custom template)

Comment: afaik ControlTemplates are the best solution to the type of cusotmization you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would put a button in it without customizing the Thumb.  If you're interested in customization:

It looks like [this](http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/customize-a-slider-in-wpf-step-by-step-tutorial/) sample customizes the Thumb as well as the rest of the slider.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomThumbForSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Ellipse Fill="#FF8F4040" Stroke="#FF000000" Height="15" Width="15"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Having never personally done this, my guess would be that you just replace the following portion with the control template you're using:

```
<Ellipse Fill="#FF8F4040" Stroke="#FF000000" Height="15" Width="15"/>
```

EDIT:  Unless you explicitly need the functionality of a button, you should probably use something like a `TextBlock` to display your value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but : the whole interest of WPF is the ability to customize each element with [ControlTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx). Here is an article from Josh Smith explaining it : [Understanding Templates in WPF](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/15/understanding-templates-in-wpf/) and here a tutorial on customizing sliders : [Custom sliders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx).

Edit: forgot to put the link title. My bad.

Comment: where is a tutotial on custom sliders? You have not posted all text